# Autowiring with Ninject

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I have a WinForms application that I've recently started using Ninject with.  The majority of the tutorials for Ninject show the setup for autowiring like this:

```
using (IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel())
{
     kernel.Bind<ITaxCalculator>()
        .To<TaxCalculator>()
        .WithConstructorArgument("rate", .2M);

     var tc = kernel.Get<ITaxCalculator>();
     Assert.Equal(20M, tc.CalculateTax(100M));
}
```

That's great if you intend on implementing that class at startup for a short script, but I'm not sure how to use those objects in my other classes and libraries in the application.  I was curious if Ninject can handle dependencies similar to Spring in [this article](http://www.vogella.com/articles/SpringDependencyInjection/article.html).

```
package testbean;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import writer.IWriter;

@Service
public class MySpringBeanWithDependency {
    private IWriter writer;

    @Autowired
    public void setWriter(IWriter writer) {
        this.writer = writer;
    }

    public void run() {
        String s = "This is my test";
        writer.writer(s);
    }
}
```

You then are able to specify in the XML which instance to inject into IWriter.  Then to run the code this is all that is needed:

```
package main;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import testbean.MySpringBeanWithDependency;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-    INF/beans.xml");
        BeanFactory factory = context;
        MySpringBeanWithDependency test = (MySpringBeanWithDependency) factory
                .getBean("mySpringBeanWithDependency");
        test.run();
    }
}
```

With Spring, it can create and inject the IWriter dependency automatically so you don't have to worry about how to get it to the rest of your application.  Using the current Ninject tutorials I have been unable to find a way to do this and have resorted to storing the objects into another object and then calling that, which isn't the best way to do it.

I've looked high and low for a way to autowire dependencies with Ninject but haven't found an answer to this particular question.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The prefered way is to do constructor injection

```
public class MySpringBeanWithDependency {
    private IWriter writer;

    public MySpringBeanWithDependency(IWriter writer) {
        this.writer = writer;
    }

    public void run() {
        String s = "This is my test";
        writer.writer(s);
    }
}

Kernel.Bind<IWriter>().To<SomeWriter>();
Kernel.Get<MySpringBeanWithDependency>();
```

Instead of one by one bindings like above you should use conventions to specify your bindings https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions/wiki/What-is-configuration-by-convention

And you should think in much bigger terms and get as much as possible with one single get at application start.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!  Will check out the extensions dll.